Through my winform application data is not inserted in the table
I have created a Winforms application using SQL Server for the database. The problem is that, after the code executes successfully, the data is not being inserted into the table. I have verified that the connection string is correct and the code appears to be correct as well, but the data still isn't being inserted. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is the code I am using:
private void StoreData()
{
    try
    {
        // Log connection string details (mask sensitive information if necessary)
        LogInformation($"Attempting to open connection with connection string: {connectionString}");

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Log which database and server the connection is using
            LogInformation($"Connected to database: {connection.Database} on server: {connection.DataSource} with connection string: {connection.ConnectionString}");

            string query = "INSERT INTO Production_Master (PlanId, ModelId, PartId, Part_Sr_No, SerialId, [User], Date_Time) " +
                            "VALUES (@PlanId, @ModelId, @PartId, @Part_Sr_No, @SerialId, @User, @Date_Time)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                // Log which table is being accessed
                LogInformation("Accessing table: Production_Master");

                // Define constant values outside the loop
                command.Parameters.Add("@PlanId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _PlanId;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ModelId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _MId;
                command.Parameters.Add("@SerialId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = P_T_QR_DATA;
                command.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0; // Assuming this is a constant value

                for (int i = 0; i < partId.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Remove previously added parameters
                    command.Parameters.Remove("@PartId");
                    command.Parameters.Remove("@Part_Sr_No");
                    command.Parameters.Remove("@Date_Time");

                    // Set parameters that change per iteration
                    command.Parameters.Add("@PartId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = partId[i];
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Part_Sr_No", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Station3Part[i];
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Date_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

                    // Log the parameters being inserted
                    LogInformation($"Inserting data: PlanId={_PlanId}, ModelId={_MId}, PartId={partId[i]}, Part_Sr_No={Station3Part[i]}, SerialId={P_T_QR_DATA}, User=0, Date_Time={DateTime.Now}");

                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (rowsAffected > 0)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText($"Data for Part {partId[i]} stored successfully.\n");
                        // Log success message
                        LogInformation($"Data for PartId={partId[i]} stored successfully.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle potential insertion failure for each iteration
                        // Log an error message or display a specific message for the failed part
                        LogError($"Failed to store data for PartId={partId[i]}.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Clear variables after storing data
        tankSR = "";
        Station3Part.Clear();
        station3Tank = "";

        // Log clearing of variables
        LogInformation("Cleared variables after storing data.");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
}

Here is the log from text file...
2024-05-24 15:37:27 [INFO] Connected to database: CKDDB on server: 10.12.101.1 with connection string: Data Source=10.12.101.1;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=CKDDB;Integrated Security=False;
2024-05-24 15:37:27 [INFO] Accessing table: Production_Master
2024-05-24 15:37:27 [INFO] Cleared variables after storing data.
2024-05-24 15:41:14 [INFO] Attempting to open connection with connection string: Data Source=10.12.101.1;User ID=sa;Password=Bal@1234;Initial Catalog=CKDDB;Integrated Security=False;


Based on your logs, there seems to be no elements in partId.

is it possible that if there is no elements in the partID then loop works

when there are no elements in partID than the loop won't run, which is the idea I guess because you read data from partID to insert into the table, you cant read from something that does not exists
